# How to use "Or" / Make a different outcome

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to code a mini RPG in VB and I need a bit of help:

1. So I am trying to make it when you buy wooden shield from the shop then your defense will change.
2. I don't know if I will have to change my whole code or not so I will share a bit of it to show you, and guide some help.
3. Basically At the moment it's:

   ```
   If Progressbar2.Value = 100 Then  MsgBox("Oh Dear you have died!")`
   ```

   And the bars maximum value is default 100.. And the shop is in a different form.. (Ex. the Game is `Form1`, the Shop is `Form4`)
4. So I want to make it when I click the button it changes the values to be:

   ```
   If ProgressBar2.Value = 200 Then MsgBox("Oh Dear you have died!")
       And ProgressBar2.Maximum = 200
   ```

My Code:

```
If ProgressBar2.Value = 100 Then MsgBox("Oh dear you have died!")
If ProgressBar2.Value = 100 Then ProgressBar2.Value = 0
```

**Not in Code: Maximum is as stated above 100**

Comment: The [markdown formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) does take a little getting used to; I reformatted your question a little, but I'm not 100% I got your #4 correct. (I haven't got a clue if visual basic's `And` keyword works like that or if VB is a line-oriented language that will croak with my line-wrapping. I just hate the horizontal scrollbars so much.)

Comment: I'm not sure what it was before you reformatting sarnold, but #4 will not compile.  It should perhaps read (excuse code in comment) `If ProgressBar2.Value = 200 And ProgressBar.Maximum = 200 Then MsgBox("Oh dear you have died")`  (i.e. `And` cannot succeed the `Then` without `ElseIf <condition> ...` or `Else <condition> ...`.  Also, consider using `AndAlso` @user1008070 - it gives the effect of nesting the `If` statements without you actually having to nest them (it doesn't evaluate the succeeding predicates unless the former predicate(s) result in `True`)

Answer (score 0):

The replacement for your code above:

```
if ProgressBar2.Value = 100 then
    MsgBox("Oh dear, you have died!")
    ProgressBar2.Value = 0
end if
```

You enclose your statements in `if...then` and `end if` to do multiple things if the condition matches.  same with loops, etc.  (though `for` loops end with `next`.)